# How would I load a Texture2d in another class?

Tags: c#, monogame, texture2d

Here’s some of my code for the player class.

```
namespace My_Game.Content.Sprites
{
    internal class Player : Sprites
    {
        public Player() {
            setDefaultVariables();
        }
        public Player(ContentManager content)
        {
            loadTexture(content);
        }


        private void setDefaultVariables() {

            position.X = Global.WIDTH / 2 - 8;
            position.Y = Global.HEIGHT / 2 - 8;

            color = Color.White;

            speed = 200;

        }

        private void loadTexture(ContentManager content)
        {
            texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Gold Idle");
        }


        public void update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            var kstate = Keyboard.GetState();
            float deltaTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

           
            //collsisions with side of screen
            if (position.X <= 0)
            {
                position.X = 0;
            }
            if (position.X >= Global.WIDTH - texture.Width)
            {
                position.X = Global.WIDTH - texture.Width;
            }
            if (position.Y <= 0)
            {
                position.Y = 0;
            }
            if (position.Y >= Global.HEIGHT - texture.Height)
            {
                position.Y = Global.HEIGHT - texture.Height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the texture is set to null when I call it in the collisions section.
I put the first player constructor in the Game1 class, and I put the other in the LoadContent function.

Comment: Did it also correctly load the texture in the other class? I think it's best to load all textures in one place (LoadContent), then use these texture variables in other classes. (My Monogame is rusty, so I'm not sure if I did it different back then)

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of context. This should work if everything works well in your other classes. But based on the code you've provided there's no way to tell.

Comment: I would recommend making a GlobalContent class with a static Load(path) function.

Comment: "_I put the first player constructor in the Game1 class, and I put the other in the LoadContent function._" - How can you be constructing the same object twice in different places? I assure that you are overwriting you object with the second constructor call, so `loadTexture` is never called and `texture` is null.